# _error_messages does not work for forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am working on a project that a user can create a post and others can send posts about that topic.My resources file is :

```
resources :users
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

    resources :topics , only: [ :show, :create, :destroy] do
    resources :posts, only: [:create, :new]
```

My topics_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@topic) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :title, placeholder: "yeni başlık girin..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Gönder", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

my create action is :

```
    def create
    @topic = current_user.topics.build(params[:topic])  
    if @topic.save
        flash[:success] = "Konu oluşturuldu!"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'static_pages/home'
    end
end
```

My posts_form.html.erb is :

```
<%= form_for [@topic, @post] do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "yorumunuzu girin..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Gönder", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

my post_controller create action is :

```
def create
    @topic= Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = @topic.posts.build(params[:post])
    @post.user = current_user
    @post.topic_id = @topic.id

    if @post.save
        flash[:success] = "Yorum oluşturuldu!"
        redirect_to topic_path(@topic)
    else
        render 'static_pages/home'
    end
end
```

This is my error_messages.html.erb:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>* <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If I test the empty post and empty topic. I get this error :

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #2):

1: 
2: <% @topics.each do |topic|%>  
3:   <li><%=link_to topic.title, topic_path(topic) %></li>  
4: 
5:  <%= will_paginate @topics %>
```

My static_pages_controller.rb :

```
  def home
        if signed_in?
        @topic = current_user.topics.build if signed_in?
        end
        @topics = Topic.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20
  end
```

and my home.html.erb:

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <div class="row">
        <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
        <%= render 'shared/topic_form' %>       
    <ol class="topics-signedin">
    <%= render 'shared/topics' %>
   </ol>
```

Why does not errors does not show ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing @topics in your 'create' action. Yes, it gets set in your 'home', which rendered the form, but on submission, it passed to 'create', which then has to load the variables again, and in your case, there is no @topics set when it goes to render 'static_pages/home'. You need..

```
...
if @post.save
  flash[:success] = "Yorum oluşturuldu!"
  redirect_to topic_path(@topic)
else
  @topics = Topic.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20
  render 'static_pages/home'
end
```

Comment: I used the lines in my topics controller .I can show topics errors now. But i cant show the posts error. I am trying to find a way for @posts

Comment: It should be all the same logic?

Comment: Yes sure I user this line but it does not show :        @posts = @topic.posts.paginate(page: params[:page])
redirect_to topic_path(@topic)

Comment: Do you get an error on @posts? Does you topic model have 'has_many :posts'?

Answer (score 0):

You never set `@topics`, only `@topic`. So `@topics` is nil.

And on error you render the `static_pages/home`, which requires those. You should re-render the `new` or `edit` instead.

Comment: I have shown static_pages.controller. Does not it get @topics from that controller?